# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 't1_0.division' in 'field list' using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Im getting the following Exception while executing the query:

`this.session.createQuery("from Team where id=1234").getSingleResult();`

When I run the query I will get:

```
Hibernate: select t1_0.team_id,t1_0.team_abbr,t1_0.division,t1_0.team_name,t1_0.score from team t1_0 where t1_0.team_id=1234

org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions 
WARN: SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22 
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions 
Exception in thread "main" jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: Converting org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException to JPA PersistenceException : JDBC exception executing SQL \[select t1_0.team_id,t1_0.team_abbr,t1_0.division,t1_0.team_name,t1_0.score from team t1_0 where t1_0.team_id=1234\] <5 internal lines>
    at de.zahrie.trues.truebot.PrimeData.init(PrimeData.java:47)
    at de.zahrie.trues.truebot.PrimeData.init(PrimeData.java:47)
    at de.zahrie.trues.truebot.PrimeData.getInstance(PrimeData.java:23)
    at de.zahrie.trues.truebot.handler.LoadupManager.init(LoadupManager.java:16)
    at de.zahrie.trues.truebot.Bot.main(Bot.java:9)

Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: JDBC exception executing SQL \[select t1_0.team_id,t1_0.team_abbr,t1_0.division,t1_0.team_name,t1_0.score from team t1_0 where t1_0.team_id=1234\] <21 internal lines>

Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 't1_0.division' in 'field list'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:916)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:972) 
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.DeferredResultSetAccess.executeQuery(DeferredResultSetAccess.java:217)
```

When I run the same query in the MySQL-Workbench I get:

| team_id | team_abbr | division | team_name | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | TEST | Division 0 | Testteam | 0:0 |

Here is my Entity-Class:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Entity(name = "Team")
@Table(name = "team", schema = "test")
public class Team implements Serializable {
  @Serial
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -8929555475128771601L;

  @Id
  @Column(name = "team_id", nullable = false)
  private int id;

  @Column(name = "team_name", nullable = false, length = 100)
  private String name;

  @Column(name = "team_abbr", nullable = false, length = 50)
  private String abbreviation;

  @Column(name = "division", length = 46)
  private String divisionName;

  @Column(name = "score", length = 30)
  private String score;

}
```

I have tried nearly everything:

- I renamed the column in `division_name`, `div` and `div_name`.
- I have removed this single column (after that it works).
- I tried `session.get(Team.class, 1234);`
- I tried NamedQuery, NativeQuery and HQLQuery.
- I used the Schema-Definition in my `hibernate.cfg.xml` and inside the Entity-Class.
- I extracted the `division` into a MappedClass

but nothing helps. No other post on Stackoverflow could give me an answer. What is the issue?

I renamed the column in division_name, div and div_name.
I have removed this single column.
I tried session.get(Team.class, 1234);
I tried NamedQuery, NativeQuery and HQLQuery.
I used the Schema-Definition in my hibernate.cfg.xml and inside the Entity-Class.
I extracted the division into a MappedClass

Comment: It only works if division and score are commented out.

Comment: What happens if you execute the following from MySQL-Workbench: select t1_0.team_id,t1_0.team_abbr,t1_0.division,t1_0.team_name,t1_0.score from team t1_0 where t1_0.team_id=1234

Comment: @JohnWilliams I get the same result as shown in the table above (in my post).

Comment: Inexplicable?? You are pointing to the same db instance with the same credentials?

Comment: Yes its the same database/schema. Credentials are also the same. Could it be an issue with jakarta.persistence? Should I use javax.persistence instead?

Comment: Unlikely, but when reasonable fixes fail then unreasonable fixes have to be attempted.

Comment: You are using the schema "test" for your MySQL-Workbench calls? There may be 2 versions of table "team". One in the "test" schema without the division and score columns and another elsewhere that MySQL-Workbench calls that has the columns.

Comment: `SELECT table_schema, table_name
from information_schema.tables where table_name='team‘` returns only one entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue:
My hibernate.cfg looked like this:

```
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bot?serverTimezone=UTC</property>
<property name="hibernate.default_schema">test</property>
```

The MySQL-User is named `bot` and the other database as well. I thought the argument inside the url is the MySQL user, not the name of the schema. Therefore it was looking inside an other schema. Replacing it like below solves the problem.

```
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?serverTimezone=UTC</property>
<property name="hibernate.default_schema">test</property>
```